# NSThread + Using UIkit (UIImage)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Error-
Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now

Im running a NSThread to download an image and display it, which is all in a method which is ran an other thread.

problem im getting is, when i try to set the `UIImageView.image = image`, it crashes because im in the 2nd thread.

How could i make it, so that this line is ran by the main thread from within the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [read and understand this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Then try something like `[myView performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setImage:) withObject: image waitUntilDone: NO];`.

Whether or not you wait until done might actually be tricky depending on how your code is threaded....